# Speeding up operation on matrix columns in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

My dataset looks like the following `R` dataset

```
dat <- data.frame(z = seq(0.5, 1,0.1), matrix(1:24, nrow = 6) )
colnames(dat) <- c("z", "A", "B", "C", "D")
dat
#   z  A  B  C  D
#  0.5 1  7 13 19
#  0.6 2  8 14 20
#  0.7 3  9 15 21
#  0.8 4 10 16 22
#  0.9 5 11 17 23
#  1.0 6 12 18 24
```

I would like to perform the same operation for each entry in columns `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`, such that I need to add another column to `dat` where for each one of these column I sum the entry in each row of the remaining three columns, divide this sum by the standard deviation of the row entries, and multiply this ratio by the corresponding row value in column `z`. For example, take the first entry in column `A`. The operation is `0.5 * (7 + 13 + 19) / sd(c(7, 13, 19))`. For the second entry in column `B`, it would be `0.6 * (2 + 14 + 20) / sd(c(2, 14, 20))`. These operations yield a `6 x 4` matrix, which I need to attach to `dat`.

My dataset is huge (and I would like to have the function in a way that I can bootstrap it quickly), so I am wondering which one is the fastest way to this. The `for` loop is quite slow (and it would make bootstrapping a nightmare). I was thinking about the `dplyr` package, but I'm not very familiar. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one for loop is enough for this:

```
m=function(x,y){
   l=unlist(dat[y,names(dat)!=x])
   unname(l[1]*sum(l[-1])/sd(l[-1]))
 }
 matrix(mapply(m,names(dat)[-1],t(row(dat[-1]))),nrow(dat),byrow = T)
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3] [,4]
[1,] 3.25 1.800298 1.472971 1.75
[2,] 4.20 2.356753 1.963961 2.40
[3,] 5.25 2.978674 2.520417 3.15
[4,] 6.40 3.666061 3.142338 4.00
[5,] 7.65 4.418912 3.829724 4.95
[6,] 9.00 5.237229 4.582576 6.00
```

Using tidyverse:

```
dat%>%
   mutate(i=1:nrow(dat))%>%
   group_by(i)%>%
   gather(key,val,-i)%>%
   summarise(s=list(map_dbl(2:ncol(dat),
       ~val[1]*sum(val[-c(1,.x)])/sd(val[-c(1,.x)]))))%>%
   pull(s)%>%invoke(rbind,.)
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3] [,4]
[1,] 3.25 1.800298 1.472971 1.75
[2,] 4.20 2.356753 1.963961 2.40
[3,] 5.25 2.978674 2.520417 3.15
[4,] 6.40 3.666061 3.142338 4.00
[5,] 7.65 4.418912 3.829724 4.95
[6,] 9.00 5.237229 4.582576 6.00
```

You can also do:

```
sapply(1:4,function(x)dat[,1]*colSums(s<-t(dat[-c(1,x+1)]))/sqrt(diag(var(s))))
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3] [,4]
[1,] 3.25 1.800298 1.472971 1.75
[2,] 4.20 2.356753 1.963961 2.40
[3,] 5.25 2.978674 2.520417 3.15
[4,] 6.40 3.666061 3.142338 4.00
[5,] 7.65 4.418912 3.829724 4.95
[6,] 9.00 5.237229 4.582576 6.00
```

Comment: I accepted this solution because the `tidyverse` seems to be the fastest approach. Thank you, and thank you to everyone else for their answers

Comment: I believe sapply is slower than the `tidyverse`, right?  I'm not familiar with `tidyverse`. Could you give me the intuition of what the `map_dbl` line does (of course it performs the operation, but I don't get how it is done)?

Comment: You can actually do a microbench on all these solutions. And you will be able to determine the fastest.

Comment: the last `sapply` is the fastest actually, but I need to repeat the same operation multiple times subsetting the data in different ways, so the `tidyverse` seems preferable. I need to grasp its logical structure better

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if you can avoid double loop structure especially when you have to do this operation for each element, however one way we could do this.

```
dat[paste0("operation", letters[1:4])] <-  t(apply(dat, 1, function(x) 
 sapply(x[-1], function(y) x[1] * sum(setdiff(x[-1], y))/sd(setdiff(x[-1], y)))))


dat
#    z A  B  C  D operationa operationb operationc operationd
#1 0.5 1  7 13 19       3.25   1.800298   1.472971       1.75
#2 0.6 2  8 14 20       4.20   2.356753   1.963961       2.40
#3 0.7 3  9 15 21       5.25   2.978674   2.520417       3.15
#4 0.8 4 10 16 22       6.40   3.666061   3.142338       4.00
#5 0.9 5 11 17 23       7.65   4.418912   3.829724       4.95
#6 1.0 6 12 18 24       9.00   5.237229   4.582576       6.00
```

Here, we first loop through each row and then for each element in that row, we exclude one element at a time and calculate `sum` and `sd` of remaining elements and then multiply it with the first element in that row. We attach this new matrix as new columns in the original data frame.

Answer (score 4):

Behold! Some convoluted data.table code:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[, row := .I]
mdat <- melt(dat, id.vars=c("row","z"))
dcast(mdat[,
     mdat[.BY[1], on="row"][!.BY[2], on="variable", sum(value)/sd(value)*z[1], by=row],
     by=.(row,variable)
     ][,-1], row ~ variable, value.var="V1")

#   row    A        B        C    D
#1:   1 3.25 1.800298 1.472971 1.75
#2:   2 4.20 2.356753 1.963961 2.40
#3:   3 5.25 2.978674 2.520417 3.15
#4:   4 6.40 3.666061 3.142338 4.00
#5:   5 7.65 4.418912 3.829724 4.95
#6:   6 9.00 5.237229 4.582576 6.00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dat2 <- cbind(dat, matrix(c(
    dat$z * rowSums(dat[,c("B", "C", "D")]) / apply(dat[,c("B", "C", "D")], 1, function(x) {sd(x)}),
    dat$z * rowSums(dat[,c("A", "C", "D")]) / apply(dat[,c("A", "C", "D")], 1, function(x) {sd(x)}),
    dat$z * rowSums(dat[,c("A", "B", "D")]) / apply(dat[,c("A", "B", "D")], 1, function(x) {sd(x)}),
    dat$z * rowSums(dat[,c("A", "B", "C")]) / apply(dat[,c("A", "B", "C")], 1, function(x) {sd(x)})
    ), ncol = 4, dimnames = list(c(1:6), paste0(LETTERS[1:4], "_operation"))))

    z A  B  C  D A_operation B_operation C_operation D_operation
1 0.5 1  7 13 19        3.25    1.800298    1.472971        1.75
2 0.6 2  8 14 20        4.20    2.356753    1.963961        2.40
3 0.7 3  9 15 21        5.25    2.978674    2.520417        3.15
4 0.8 4 10 16 22        6.40    3.666061    3.142338        4.00
5 0.9 5 11 17 23        7.65    4.418912    3.829724        4.95
6 1.0 6 12 18 24        9.00    5.237229    4.582576        6.00

0.5 * (7 + 13 + 19) / sd(c(7, 13, 19)) == dat2[1,"A_operation"]
[1] TRUE
0.6 * (2 + 14 + 20) / sd(c(2, 14, 20)) == dat2[2,"B_operation"]
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `mutate_at` can be achieved bu accessing current column name in `.funs` and then excluding it. The basic trick is to `group_by` on `row_number` so that calculations `i.e. rowSums and sd` happen for each row.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% group_by(grp = row_number()) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(A:D), 
        funs(New = z*rowSums(dat[grp,!names(dat) %in% c("z",quo_name(quo(.)))])/
              sd(dat[grp,!names(dat) %in% c("z",quo_name(quo(.)))]))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp) %>% as.data.frame()

#     z A  B  C  D A_New    B_New    C_New D_New
# 1 0.5 1  7 13 19  3.25 1.800298 1.472971  1.75
# 2 0.6 2  8 14 20  4.20 2.356753 1.963961  2.40
# 3 0.7 3  9 15 21  5.25 2.978674 2.520417  3.15
# 4 0.8 4 10 16 22  6.40 3.666061 3.142338  4.00
# 5 0.9 5 11 17 23  7.65 4.418912 3.829724  4.95
# 6 1.0 6 12 18 24  9.00 5.237229 4.582576  6.00
```

Note: A little optimization is possible in above approach by `.funs` argument having a custom function with search for column names are done only once.

Comment: `rowwise` May not work as function in `mutate_at` access data frame with row number by excluding columns.